# .html() not showing the whole text that contains the ' character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i try to edit the value on fields that contain the ' character in them, it cuts the string to that character. For example if I put O'Hara as name a try to edit it, it will give me only the O from O'Hara. Also on a side note is this "valid", correct way to edit the values of the properties on the the contact objects? Thanks in advance.

```
    class Contact{

    constructor(id, first, last, email, password, phone) {
        this.id = id || "WTF";
        this.first = first || this.get_Random_F_name();
        this.last = last || this.get_Random_F_name();
        this.email = email || (this.get_Random_F_name() + "@hotmail.com");
        this.password = password || Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(90000));
        this.phone = phone || Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(500));
    }
    get_Random_F_name(){
        let cityIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(9));
        if(cityIndex == 0){
            return "O'mara"
        }
        else if(cityIndex == 1){
            return "F'airfax"
        }
        else if(cityIndex == 2){
            return "C'harlie"
        }
        else if(cityIndex == 3){
            return "Evereteze"
        }
        else if(cityIndex == 4){
            return "H'errera"
        }
        else if(cityIndex == 5){
            return "Guerriero"
        }
        else if(cityIndex == 6){
            return "I'mperio"
        }
        else if(cityIndex == 7){
            return "Levitan"
        }
        else {
            return "A'mato"
        }
    }

}


function dontCoptThatFloppy(id, first, last, email, password, phone) {

    let proactiveBitch = ("<tr><td class='td-id'>"+ id +
    "</td><td class='f_Name'>"+first+
    "</td><td class='l_Name'>"+last+
    "</td><td class='e_mail'>"+email+
    "</td><td class='pass_in'>"+password+
    "</td><td class='phone_in'>"+phone+
    "</td><td class='td-three-Btn'><button class='save-Btn'>save</button>"+
    "<button class='edit-Btn'>edit</button><button class='del-Btn'>Broken</button></td>"+ 
    "<td class='td-del'><button class='del-row'>Del</button></td>"+"</tr>")

    return proactiveBitch;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    let idCounter = 1;

    let a_contacts = [];
    let a_contacts2 = [];
    let a_contacts3 = [];
    let contacts_arr_obj = [];
    let new_contacts_arr_obj = contacts_arr_obj;

        $('#new-row-btn').click(function(){

            let newContact = new Contact(idCounter, $("#name-input").val(), $("#lastname-input").val(), $("#email-input").val(), $("#pass-input").val(), $("#phone-input").val());

            $("#my-table").append(dontCoptThatFloppy(idCounter, newContact.first, newContact.last, newContact.email, newContact.password, newContact.phone))

            a_contacts.push(newContact);

            $("#name-input").val("")
            $("#lastname-input").val("")
            $("#email-input").val("")
            $("#pass-input").val("")
            $("#phone-input").val("")
            idCounter++;

        });

        $(document).on('click', '.del-row', function (event) {
            $(event.target).parent().parent().remove()

    });


        $(document).on('click', '.edit-Btn', function (event) {

            var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var id = $row.find('.td-id').text();
            var fName = a_contacts[id-1].first;
            var lName = a_contacts[id-1].last;
            var email = a_contacts[id-1].email;
            var pass = a_contacts[id-1].password;
            var phone = a_contacts[id-1].phone;


            let my_input_f_Name = "<input class='in_f_name' type='text' value='"+fName+"'>"
            let my_input_l_Name = "<input class='in_l_name' type='text' value='"+lName+"'>"
            let my_input_e_mail = "<input class='in_e_mail' type='text' value='"+email+"'>"
            let my_input_pass = "<input class='in_pass_in' type='text' value='"+pass+"'>"
            let my_input_phone = "<input class='in_phone_in' type='text' value='"+phone+"'>"

            $row.find('.f_Name').html(my_input_f_Name)
            $row.find('.l_Name').html(my_input_l_Name)
            $row.find('.e_mail').html(my_input_e_mail)
            $row.find('.pass_in').html(my_input_pass)
            $row.find('.phone_in').html(my_input_phone)


            let edit = $row.find('.edit-Btn')
            let del_btn = $row.find('.del-Btn')
            let save_btn = $row.find('.save-Btn')

            edit.css('display','none');
            del_btn.css('display','none');
            save_btn.css('display','block');
        });


        $(document).on('click', '.save-Btn', function (event) {

            var $row = $(this).closest('tr');

            var id = $row.find('.td-id').text();

            a_contacts[id-1].first = $row.find('.in_f_name').val();
            a_contacts[id-1].last = $row.find('.in_l_name').val();
            a_contacts[id-1].email = $row.find('.in_e_mail').val();
            a_contacts[id-1].password = $row.find('.in_pass_in').val();
            a_contacts[id-1].phone = $row.find('.in_phone_in').val();


            $row.find('.f_Name').html( a_contacts[id-1].first);
            $row.find('.l_Name').html(a_contacts[id-1].last);
            $row.find('.e_mail').html(a_contacts[id-1].email);
            $row.find('.pass_in').html(a_contacts[id-1].password);
            $row.find('.phone_in').html(a_contacts[id-1].phone);



            let edit = $row.find('.edit-Btn')
            let del_btn = $row.find('.del-Btn')
            let save_btn = $row.find('.save-Btn')

            edit.css('display','inline');
            del_btn.css('display','inline');
            save_btn.css('display','none');

        });



        $(document).on('click', '#sup', function (event) {

            console.log(a_contacts);

        });



        $("#sort").on("change", function(event){

            let pickedValue = event.target.value;
            let table = $('#my-table')
            let rows = table.find('.td-id').toArray()


                if (pickedValue === "1"){
                    a_contacts.sort(function(a, b){
                        return a.id - b.id;
                    });
                }
                else if (pickedValue === "2"){
                    a_contacts.sort(function(a,b) {
                        return a.first.localeCompare(b.first);
                    });
                }
                else if (pickedValue === "3"){
                    a_contacts.sort(function(a,b) {
                        return a.last.localeCompare(b.last);
                    });
                }
                else if (pickedValue === "4"){
                    a_contacts.sort(function(a,b) {
                        return a.email.localeCompare(b.email);
                    });
                }
                else if (pickedValue === "5"){
                    a_contacts.sort(function(a, b){
                        return a.password - b.password;
                    });
                }
                else if (pickedValue === "6"){
                    a_contacts.sort(function(a, b){
                        return a.phone - b.phone;
                    });
                }
                else{}

                $(tbody).html("");

                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                $("#my-table").append(dontCoptThatFloppy(a_contacts[i].id, a_contacts[i].first, a_contacts[i].last, a_contacts[i].email, a_contacts[i].password, a_contacts[i].phone))
                }

        });

});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CSS/style.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="inputs-div">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name Sir" id="name-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Last Name Sir" id="lastname-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email Sir" id="email-input">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Your Password Sir" id="pass-input" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Phone Number" id="phone-input" >
            <button id="new-row-btn">Add Contact</button>
            <button id="sup">Console.Log</button>
        </div>


        <select class="custom-select" id="sort">
                <option selected>Choose...</option>
                <option value="1">ID</option>
                <option value="2">First Name</option>
                <option value="3">Last Name</option>
                <option value="4">Email</option>
                <option value="5">Password</option>
                <option value="6">Phone</option>
        </select>


        <div>
            <table id="my-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr id="first-row">
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>


        <script src="JS/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: wheat;
}

input{
    display: block;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 2px solid #ac7b11;
    background-color: rgba(44, 42, 42, 0.863);
    color: #bebe35;

}
::placeholder { 
    color: #bebe35;
}
button{
    background-color: #1a64a0;
    border: 2px solid #1a64a0;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline:none;

    /* text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle; */
}
#new-row-btn, #sup{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 3px;
}
.del-row{
    /* display: flex; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* margin:  0px auto; */
    /* text-align: 0px auto; */
}

.small-Btn, .medium-Btn{
    display: none;
}

.del-Btn, .edit-Btn{
    background-color: #10b133;
    border: 2px solid #10b133;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.save-Btn{
    background-color: #a1b110;
    border: 2px solid #a1b110;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
th{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}
td{
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}
.td-id{
    width: 30px; 
    text-align: center;
}
#my-table tbody tr td {
    background-color: #a35635;
}

#my-table tbody tr td:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #828e20;
}
.td-del, .td-three-Btn{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

td input{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write something like this:

```
let my_input_f_Name = "<input class='in_f_name' type='text' value='"+fName+"'>"
```

if the value of `fName` is `O'hara`, the resulting HTML is:

```
<input class='in_f_name' type='text' value='O'hara'>
```

The `'` in the name matches the `'` that starts the `value` attribute, so it ends the attribute; it's equivalen to writing

```
<input class='in_f_name' type='text' value='O' hara'>
```

Since you're using jQuery, you can use its methods to create your elements instead of concatenating strings:

```
let my_input_f_Name = $("<input>", {
    "class": "in_f_name",
    type: "text",
    value: fName
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar!